# Preview image URL on production site

Tags: 2013, image, preview

I am kind of new to Tridion and I'm currently working on Tridion 2013.

I work on a website that has different versions (for different languages for many countries in Europe).

On a specific page, there is an image that doesn't display on a certain website (the Czech one), although it displays correctly on others (French, German, etc.).

When I check this image with the web inspector, it appears that the image URL on Czech site contains "preview" in it, and not on other countries. So it is like `//files.preview.nameOfCompany.com...` on CZ site (where it fails) and `//files.nameOfCompany.com...` on all other websites.

I'm trying to find a way to get rid of that "preview" that seems to break my image. I tried publishing the image file on Tridion, then publish the Landing Page Component, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you share some details about the implementation, what Templating model is used etc.?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but here it is : 
there are many folders, all starting with a number : 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600 and 610. 
550 is the "source", where, for example, we create Multimedia components that will be used in other folders
560/70/80 are where the components are created, modified.
590/600/610 are where the pages & components are published.

Comment: That sounds more like the Publications you are talking about, for anybody to be able to give a useful answer, we need to know more details about the technical side of things. Are you using VBScript Templates, or DWT Templates, or are you perhaps using DD4T or DXA? It may be that you don't even know these technical details, in which case I think you should probabaly want to contact the person that set everything up in the first place, so they can share these details.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the issue, I don't have access to these tools right now, I asked the person in charge. Thank you I'll come back here if I have any more details